# remove unsuccessfully installed ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I tried installing ubuntu 12.04 32-bit along side windows 8, and I encountered an error. I determined that I need to install the 64-bit version instead. I need to delete the old directory containing the files associated with the old ubuntu installation. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot into LiveCD of Ubuntu
2. Install gparted

   - `sudo apt-get install gparted`
3. Run gparted
4. Select the HDD containing your Ubuntu installation
5. Be very careful to select the partition containing your Ubuntu installation.
6. **Check again that this is *not* your Windows partition**
7. Delete said partition (there may be more than one, depending on your setup)
8. Begin installation of Ubuntu on newly available freespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the partition with Ubuntu on, and install the 64bit one. You can do it from the installer.

Comment: Windows 8 will not allow me to do that. I insert the liveCD to the drive, and attempted to run wubi.exe from Windows 8, but it simply stops and says there's already a directory named Ubuntu and won't move forward. I also tried restarting the computer with the liveCD in the optical drive, but my computer simply starts up windows 8. How can I get around this?

Comment: Dont use Wubi on a Win8 PC... Install from the LiveCD after booting from it. Hit F10 or F12 when you start the computer for a boot menu. Or hit F2/Del to get into "BIOS" settings to change boot settings...